# decimal to ascii android

Tags: android, binary

I am attempting to implement a conversion from a decimal number to ascii. Right now, i've hard coded it to 50 but I will use userinput later on. When I run the application and call the method, what is outputed is random (it changes everytime I press it) eg "[C@4263f600"

I followed the process in the link: [decimal to binary](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary). Why am I getting such a weird output?

```
//method
if (valid) {
     String str = ascii();
     mTextOutput.setText(str);

...

public String ascii(){
    char[] binary_reverse = new char[9];
    char[] binary = new char[9];

    int ascii = 50;
    int y = 0;

    while (ascii !=1) {
        if (ascii % 2 ==0)
        {
            binary_reverse[y]='0';
        }
        else if (ascii % 2 == 1)
        {
            binary_reverse[y]='1';
        }
        ascii /= 2;
        y++;
    }

    if (ascii ==1)
    {
        binary_reverse[y] = '1';
    }

    if (y<8) {
        for(; y < 8; y++) {
            binary_reverse[y] = '0';
        }
    }

    for (int z = 0; z < 8; z++) {
        binary[z] = binary_reverse[7-1];
    }

    String str = binary.toString();
    return str;
}
```

Comment: `binary[z] = binary_reverse[7-1];` - So you want to set every element of `binary` to the value in `binary_reverse[6]`?

Comment: nice find! I got it to work now. I also replaced String str = binary.toString(); to String str = new String(binary); Ty Tim!

Comment: I think this is answered question and a user when look this he/she should see the answer too so I answeren this question with @Tim reply,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//You can try this :

```
binary[z] = binary_reverse[7-1]; - So you want to set every element of binary to the value in binary_reverse[6]
```

//and also

```
 String str = binary.toString(); to String str = new String(binary);
```

***reference : @Tim***